# Python how to merge the time spans and make a bigger one

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timespan, relative-time-span

I have the following dataframe.

```
       padel start_time  end_time  duration
38  Padel 10   08:00:00  09:00:00        60
40  Padel 10   10:00:00  11:30:00        90
42  Padel 10   10:30:00  12:00:00        90
44  Padel 10   11:00:00  12:30:00        90
46  Padel 10   11:30:00  13:00:00        90
49  Padel 10   16:00:00  17:30:00        90
51  Padel 10   16:30:00  18:00:00        90
53  Padel 10   17:00:00  18:30:00        90
55  Padel 10   17:30:00  19:00:00        90
57  Padel 10   18:00:00  19:30:00        90
59  Padel 10   18:30:00  20:00:00        90
61  Padel 10   19:00:00  20:30:00        90
63  Padel 10   19:30:00  21:00:00        90
65  Padel 10   20:00:00  21:30:00        90
67  Padel 10   20:30:00  22:00:00        90
```

I want to chose the longest timespans in between. The output I want should look like this

```
       padel start_time  end_time  duration
38  Padel 10   08:00:00  09:00:00        60
40  Padel 10   10:00:00  13:00:00        180
49  Padel 10   16:00:00  22:00:00        360
```

I not care about duration. I can do that. but how  will i merge the time spans which overlap.
Thanks

Comment: do you have to do it byu group? with `padel` column?

Comment: good question. If so, add padel to the sort (first), and add `and row['padel'] == next_row['padel']` to the `elif` condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use `shift()` to create groups if `start_time` is `greater than` `end_time` of row above (i.e. overlapping).
2. We `fillna` with `'24:00:00'` so that we return 'True' for first value as nothing can be greater than 24 hours for a day. That's because `NaN` is the output in first row with `shift()` which would return `False` if we didn't do this.
3. That returns a `boolean` series of `True` and `False` (i.e. `1` and `0`,. respectively), so you just take the cumulative sum with `cumsum`.
4. This creates a `grp` object, which we can include in `groupby`.

---

```
df = df.sort_values(by=['padel', 'start_time'], ascending=[True, True])
grp = df['start_time'].gt(df['end_time'].shift().fillna('24:00:00')).cumsum() 
df = df.groupby([grp, 'padel'], as_index=False).agg({'start_time':'first', 'end_time':'last'})
df['duration'] = ((pd.to_timedelta(df['end_time']) - 
                   pd.to_timedelta(df['start_time'])).dt.seconds / 60).astype(int)
Out[1]: 
      padel start_time  end_time  duration
0  Padel 10   08:00:00  09:00:00        60
1  Padel 10   10:00:00  13:00:00       180
2  Padel 10   16:00:00  22:00:00       360
```

---

**Full Code with input dataframe**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.DataFrame({'padel': {38: 'Padel 10',
  40: 'Padel 10',
  42: 'Padel 10',
  44: 'Padel 10',
  46: 'Padel 10',
  49: 'Padel 10',
  51: 'Padel 10',
  53: 'Padel 10',
  55: 'Padel 10',
  57: 'Padel 10',
  59: 'Padel 10',
  61: 'Padel 10',
  63: 'Padel 10',
  65: 'Padel 10',
  67: 'Padel 10'},
 'start_time': {38: '08:00:00',
  40: '10:00:00',
  42: '10:30:00',
  44: '11:00:00',
  46: '11:30:00',
  49: '16:00:00',
  51: '16:30:00',
  53: '17:00:00',
  55: '17:30:00',
  57: '18:00:00',
  59: '18:30:00',
  61: '19:00:00',
  63: '19:30:00',
  65: '20:00:00',
  67: '20:30:00'},
 'end_time': {38: '09:00:00',
  40: '11:30:00',
  42: '12:00:00',
  44: '12:30:00',
  46: '13:00:00',
  49: '17:30:00',
  51: '18:00:00',
  53: '18:30:00',
  55: '19:00:00',
  57: '19:30:00',
  59: '20:00:00',
  61: '20:30:00',
  63: '21:00:00',
  65: '21:30:00',
  67: '22:00:00'},
 'duration': {38: 60,
  40: 90,
  42: 90,
  44: 90,
  46: 90,
  49: 90,
  51: 90,
  53: 90,
  55: 90,
  57: 90,
  59: 90,
  61: 90,
  63: 90,
  65: 90,
  67: 90}}))
grp = df['start_time'].gt(df['end_time'].shift().fillna('24:00:00')).cumsum() 
df = df.groupby([grp, 'padel'], as_index=False).agg({'start_time':'first', 'end_time':'last'})
df['duration'] = ((pd.to_timedelta(df['end_time']) - \
                   pd.to_timedelta(df['start_time'])).dt.seconds / 60).astype(int)
df
```

Comment: That's not giving correct output
```
Out[61]: 
      padel start_time  end_time  duration
0  Padel 10   09:00:00  14:00:00       300
1  Padel 10   15:00:00  10:00:00      1140
```

Comment: @gulbazkhan my answer exactly matches your desired output.

Comment: but it's giving me 9 to 14. but it should give 8 to 9. I also tried changing the columns to datetime then it gave me `TypeError: dtype datetime64[ns] cannot be converted to timedelta64[ns]`

Comment: @gulbazkhan I would run the full code with input dataframe that I have included in my answer and identify what might be different with your actual data. This works 100% correctly on the sample data in your question.

Comment: Ok. Thanks That works. the data needed to be sorted first.

Comment: Aaah that makes sense @gulbazkhan if you wouldn't mind upvoting my solution as well, then I would greatly appreciate it! I have just upvoted your question as it was a good question. Also, if other solutions were helpful, then you can upvote those as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
#Coeece the start and end times to datetime
df['start_time']=pd.to_datetime(df['start_time'])
df['end_time']=pd.to_datetime(df['end_time'])

g=df.groupby(df.end_time.sub(df.start_time.shift(1)).ne('2h').cumsum()).tail(1).reset_index()#Find last entry in each set of pedal

g=g.assign(start_time=df.groupby(df.end_time.sub(df.start_time.shift(1)).ne('2h').cumsum()).start_time.head(1).reset_index().loc[:,'start_time'])#Set start_time to the start_time in each set of pedal


g=g.iloc[:,:-1].join(df.groupby(df.end_time.sub(df.start_time.shift(1)).ne('2h').cumsum()).apply(lambda x: (x['end_time'].max()-(x['start_time'].min())).total_seconds()/60).to_frame('duration').reset_index(drop=True))#Calc the duration



    padel start_time  end_time  duration
0  Padel 10   08:00:00  09:00:00        60
1  Padel 10   10:00:00  13:00:00       180
2  Padel 10   16:00:00  22:00:00       360
```

Comment: The problem is solved. Btw. Thanks. I get this when running `ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified: Index(['duration'], dtype='object')`

Comment: Works for me perfectly. What specific line in the code gives you that error?

Comment: the last line. occurs.  btw. It solved my problem. duration wasn't a bigdeal. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of an easy pandas way to do it, so I'd just go with a for loop. Haven't tested this code, but something like:

```
df = df.sort_values(...)
out_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)
next_row = None

for row in df.rows:
    if next_row is None:
        next_row = row
    elif row['start_time'] <= next_row['end_time']:
        next_row['end_time'] = row['end_time']
    else:
        out_df = out_df.append(next_row)
        next_row = None

out_df = out_df.append(next_row)
```

Comment: i should get 10:00 It gives 10:30. all other is fine. same as 16:30